# Adding OnClick(View v) in the textview's

Tags: java, android

i have added onClick in my mainactivity for my textview and i had no errors but when i run the app it crashes saying app has stopped working even though i have no errors in my codes i dont know what's the problem

i hope you can help me and thanks in advance

this is my logcat

```
12-25 03:32:44.694: I/Ads(1433): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
12-25 03:33:00.234: I/Process(1433): Sending signal. PID: 1433 SIG: 9
12-25 03:33:38.454: D/dalvikvm(1559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 4% free 3135K/3248K, paused 283ms, total 286ms
12-25 03:33:38.504: I/dalvikvm-heap(1559): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.200MB for 1127536-byte allocation
12-25 03:33:38.654: D/dalvikvm(1559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4233K/4352K, paused 146ms, total 146ms
12-25 03:33:39.144: D/dalvikvm(1559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 4238K/4352K, paused 46ms, total 47ms
12-25 03:33:39.304: I/dalvikvm-heap(1559): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.535MB for 5591056-byte allocation
12-25 03:33:39.394: D/dalvikvm(1559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 9698K/9816K, paused 84ms, total 84ms
12-25 03:33:40.284: V/WebViewChromium(1559): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b1d56e50}
12-25 03:33:40.304: I/chromium(1559): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
12-25 03:33:40.334: I/BrowserProcessMain(1559): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
12-25 03:33:40.514: D/(1559): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7a714f8, tid 1559
12-25 03:33:40.594: W/chromium(1559): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
12-25 03:33:41.664: E/ActivityThread(1559): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
12-25 03:33:41.774: I/Ads(1559): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
12-25 03:33:42.194: D/AndroidRuntime(1559): Shutting down VM
12-25 03:33:42.194: W/dalvikvm(1559): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a83ba8)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): Process: imamalsajadsayings.android.com, PID: 1559
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{imamalsajadsayings.android.com/imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     ... 11 more
12-25 03:33:43.064: D/dalvikvm(1559): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads478949099.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
12-25 03:33:46.024: D/dalvikvm(1559): DexOpt: --- END 'ads478949099.jar' (success) ---
12-25 03:33:46.024: D/dalvikvm(1559): DEX prep '/data/data/imamalsajadsayings.android.com/cache/ads478949099.jar': unzip in 54ms, rewrite 2963ms
12-25 03:33:46.844: I/Ads(1559): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"5927457787414134416","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a152b5665edfefd","u_w":384,"msid":"imamalsajadsayings.android.com","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"3.android.imamalsajadsayings.android.com","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":2,"simulator":1,"ms":"OPbcxzOd9lJImWjXOtp3hqpv26-cVzCC2CRXlOnJL4iR9JnqERa-t0gYOUEDfm9_ZdloVn6JYXvSi2W_T-OmyZGApgUSdoc5Ymf5xM0wqWv4Q1-L-cPGOlLqFb__qZoBPosFpAT3wG8rSE4SjadFbESExgSB07bJ9U3TVzf2AlhGPQR-7N41d3arIEUnV2UCOeer6Y6n_imlZs00ubvpKIcI5sAN2ZBIIoZhg4Qi35EBNf6nHyiKHVecGbgmnf6PDDO1xU1MfLOSdMQeqKZQWyiIsXWPGCBZ6wqyhJmCfeABwzF4p0G6y_gKB2r9xs_HzB4e8lrIQm_l1chnFG96Tg","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":592,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
12-25 03:33:48.574: I/Process(1559): Sending signal. PID: 1559 SIG: 9
```

and is my mainactivity.java

```
package imamalsajadsayings.android.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private LinearLayout someLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView someLayout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.state2); 
inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
runNextTask(someLayout);

}
  public void runNextTask(View v){
   LinearLayout mInflatedLayout = (LinearLayout)       inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
final TrackerInfo newInfo = new TrackerInfo();
   //set up for model selection
   someLayout.addView(mInflatedLayout);    
   someLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1); //layout present in 
   someLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       }
   });
   }


  @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return true;
 } 

}
```

and this is my mainactivity with the textviews and linearlayout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:background="@drawable/images" >



                   <com.google.ads.AdView 
                   android:id="@+id/ad"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
                   ads:adUnitId="a152b5665edfefd"
                   ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                   ads:adSize="BANNER" />




                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/state1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (من كرمت عليه نفسه هانت عليه الدنيا)                                                                         "
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"
                    android:clickable = "true"
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />




                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/state2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (الخير كله في صيانة الإنسان نفسه)                                                                "
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"             
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/state3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (ما أحب المؤمن معافى في الدنيا، وفي نفسه وماله، ولا يصاب بشيء من المصائب)"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"
                    android:clickable = "true"
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/state4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" قال (عليه السلام): (ضل من ليس له حليم يرشده، وذل من ليس له سفيه يعضده..)                                                "
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"
                    android:clickable = "true"
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/state5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (ويل لمن غلبت آحاده أعشاره)                                                                                         "
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"
                    android:clickable = "true"
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>
                </LinearLayout>

              </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why you are asking same question again.

Comment: @Raghunandan, even user's are also same.

Comment: Can you say what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: app crashing and i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

This is getting really interesting:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1559): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

the declaration:

```
private LinearLayout someLayout;
```

and another confused naming

```
TextView someLayout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.state2);
```

and, how is that possible if `someLayout` can `addView()` before loading from layout?

```
someLayout.addView(mInflatedLayout);    
someLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
```

Well, I suggest you should start with a proper basic Android learning first,

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private LinearLayout someLayout;
private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.state2 );
    mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thankss muuuuch, no more app crashing but when i click the state2 it won't work i mean it doesn't show it to me

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The guy over me had an better explanation!